# JQuery autcomplete not working with multiple input fields

Tags: jquery

I have a form with four input fields that I wish to use autocpmplete to suggest entries from a mySQL file. All four input fields will access the same data. Based on my code below, only the first input field works and returns suggestions, while the other three show nothing. How do I change the script so that autocomplete works for all four input fields?

```js
$( function() {
 $( "#artists" )
 .autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
   // Fetch data
   $.ajax({
    url: "getartists.php",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
     search: request.term
    },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( data );
    }
   });
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
     // Set selection
     $('#artists').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
     return false;
  },
  focus: function(event, ui){
     $( "#artists" ).val( ui.item.label );
     return false;
   },
 });

});
```

```html
<input name="confname1" id = "artists" value="" placeholder="Conductor name ...">
                
<input name="confname2" id = "artists" value="" placeholder="Conductor name ...">
                
<input name="confname3" id = "artists" value="" placeholder="Conductor name ...">
                
<input name="confname4" id = "artists" value="" placeholder="Conductor name ...">
```

Comment: Do not EDIT the original question with the correct answer after getting the correct answer below from me. It is against the Stackoverflow quidelines. Keep your original question as exactly you wanted and post another question if there issue is different to what is posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `class` in your input fields and make the `id` unique and not the same for every input.

Also, use `on` jQuery with input method to it which will call `autocomplete` as soon as you type two characters.

Live Demo:

```js
var dummyData = ["myname", "myage", "lol"];
$('.artist').on("input", function() {
  $(this).autocomplete({
    source: dummyData
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input name="confname1" class="artist" id="artists1" value="" placeholder="Conductor name ...">

<input name="confname2" class="artist" id="artists2" value="" placeholder="Conductor name ...">

<input name="confname3" class="artist" id="artists3" value="" placeholder="Conductor name ...">

<input name="confname4" class="artist" id="artists4" value="" placeholder="Conductor name ...">
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't get it to work with my ajax version of the script, but I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: I've amended my jquery script above based on your suggestion, but this does not work so I guess it needs tweaking somewhere. I have changed the input fields as suggested, aslo now shown above.